# How to boot ubuntu server form an ssd?

Tags: boot, server, ssd

I use an rasperry pi 4. I want to use an ssd instead of an micro sd because of speed.

But How can I boot from the ssd?

Thanks

Vale

Comment: Pi will not directly boot Ubuntu. https://medium.com/@zsmahi/make-ubuntu-server-20-04-boot-from-an-ssd-on-raspberry-pi-4-33f15c66acd4 & https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4/18925

Answer (score 1):

You can plug the SSD via USB. It would work.
USB3 is typically much faster than SD cards, but it also depends on the maximum speed of the SSD.
You can plug the SSD to USB convertor and plug it to the raspberry pi. That's what i've done.
Now, to BOOT from the SSD, take out the SD card, or format it (so it doesn't contain bootable ISO) and that's it. Raspberry pi should boot from the SSD if it contains bootable ISO.

Comment: well id did it like you told me, but now Putty can´t find the pi ...

How can I tell the pi he has to boot from the ssd?

Comment: @dasvalez What do you mean putty can't find the pi? Did the Pi boot from the SSD? Did you connect keyboard and display? Did it show anything?